# PHP Unique User Profiles URL

Tags: php

I have been working on a twitter clone for a school project the past few days but I'm stuck on setting up unique profile urls, I've done some googling and I know that I need to use $_GET but other than that there doesn't seem to really be much more info. This is the start of my profile.php. Hoping someone can help me understand $_GET more. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$MySQLi_CON->close();
?>
```

My current `GET` attempt:

```
$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=".$_GET['user_name']);
```

and my error:

> Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php on line 10 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php on line 11

When trying with:

```
<a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>"><?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?></a>
```

Comment: If you have profile.php?user=TheTezma you would use `$_GET['user']` to grab the querystring variable, and then use that in your SQL. In that example `$_GET['user']` would = `TheTezma`

Comment: Well I know that I need to switch the $_SESSION out for $_GET but it's not just as easy as changing it and tada. I want to know how $_GET works and how it's used in retrieving specific mysql data dependent on what the current url is.

Comment: http://localhost/network/profile.php?user=Admin This is the current way I have the urls setup

Comment: Okay, and the PHP usage?

Comment: <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>"><?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?></a> Problem is, on my actual profile.php page it's just showing data from my Session instead of from the user that's entered into the url

Comment: This is my current query $query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=".$_GET['user_name']); and it's outputting these errors: Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampppp\htdocs\network\profile.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET` works by taking the left value of the parameter and using it as the index, the right value is the value. So for example:

```
home.php?id=1
```

The `$_GET['id']` would be `1`. In SQL:

```
Select * from table where id = $_GET['id']
```

would be valid (very insecure, but SQL valid) because it would go to the DB as:

```
Select * from table where id = 1
```

however, loading `home.php?username=chris` with

```
select * from table where username = $_GET['username']
```

would fail because strings need to be quoted in SQL and `$_GET['username']` comes out as `chris`:

```
select * from table where username = chris
```

so

```
select * from table where username = '$_GET['username']'
```

would be valid but none of these approaches are good instead [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) should be used.

```
$prepared = $MySQLi_CON->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?');
if (!$prepared->bind_param("s", $_GET['username'])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $prepared->errno . ") " . $prepared->error;
}
if (!$prepared->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $prepared->errno . ") " . $prepared->error;
}
$returned = $prepared->get_result();
$userRow = $returned->fetch_array();
$MySQLi_CON->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, now when I go to profile.php?user=Tezma there is actually no data from the database loading into the page, not sure if I'm missing something or not.

Comment: Is the `GET` parameter named `username` or `user`? Modify the bound the value according to that name..

Comment: @TheTezma So success?